# Code For StandardController Works With One Object But Not All. Why?

Tags: opportunity, account, leads, list, standardcontroller

I have some code that works perfect for my Account standardController and an extension for a custom controller. When I go to implement the same code for Opportunity or Lead, my VF page is missing some results. I am just changing:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="noteandtask_controller">
```

to

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="noteandtask_controller">
```

I am getting back some data but not all. I am missing a row in my table. Why is this happening? I am querying tasks and notes. I thought that the relationship between Task and Account was the same between Task and Opportunity and Task and Lead. Any help would be so great!

My controller is:

```
public with sharing class noteandtask_controller {
    public List<SObject> tasksAndNotes {get; private set;}
    public List<SObject> t {get;set;}
    public List<SObject> n {get;set;}
    String actId;

    public noteandtask_controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        actId = stdController.getId();
        tasksAndNotes = new List<SObject>();
        t = [Select CreatedById, Subject, Description, CreatedDate From Task WHERE Status = 'Completed' AND AccountId = : actId];
        n = [Select CreatedById, Title, Body,CreatedDate From Note WHERE ParentId =: actId];
        tasksAndNotes.addAll(t);
        tasksAndNotes.addAll(n);

        System.debug('the  tasks list is: ' + t);
        System.debug('the  notes list is: ' + n);
        System.debug('the tasksAndNotes list is: ' + tasksAndNotes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe we probably need to see the noteandtask_controller. There's several ways you could be querying the data, and while the relationships are *similar*, you're probably running into a gotcha.

Comment: @sfdcfox I just added it

Comment: I feel like it might be a setting in my org? Or a basic connection that I am missing between the objects? Or maybe because I have looked at it a thousand times it is a gotcha.  Ah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem's with your query. You're filtering by AccountId on Task, so it doesn't work for Lead or Opportunity (because AccountId will never be a 00Q or 006 Id). Instead, try the following change:

```
        t = [Select CreatedById, Subject, Description, CreatedDate From Task WHERE Status = 'Completed' AND 
            (AccountId = :actId OR WhatId = :actId OR WhoId = :actId)];
```

This should account for any type of object for which Task is supported.

Comment: ah gotcha. I did try to change it up from AccountId to WhatId, but I didn't combine them and I didn't try WhoId. This makes sense and it works. Thank you so much!